# Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-foundation-server

recently I have Installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, Whenever I try to Install Team Foundation Server It gives me this error:

Error : TF400157 : Service Pack 1 or higher is required for this version of Windows.

This Is because I'm running a themed Windows 7 called xDark V3 or something like this, Is It possible to change name of my Windows or something else to Install Foundation Server?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the theme has anything to do with it? Try taking the error message literally and install service pack 1.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed Windows 7 Service Pack 1?  That's what the error is complaining about.   Follow the instructions here to check:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1

- learn if Windows 7 SP1 is already installed

  1. Click the Start button , right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
  2. If Service Pack 1 is listed under Windows edition, SP1 is already installed on your computer.

Comment: Technically my windows is: Windows 7 Ultimate but themed.

Comment: @user2248354 - Do you have Service Pack 1 installed?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @user2248354 Then install Windows 7 Service Pack 1 and TFS 2012 will work.

Comment: What you mean is changing my Windows, Is it possible to download something like this to fix it?

Comment: @user2248354 - yes it is a free download.  Either through Windows Update or through Microsoft.  Follow the link in my answer for more instructions.